# Сгенерировать PDF из View

Tags: android

нашла метод для генерации pdf из view. Но получаю ошибку в строке `Bitmap bitmap = loadBitmapFromView(pdf, pdf.getWidth(), pdf.getHeight());`

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.getWidth()' on a null object reference

```
public class PDFActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LinearLayout pdf;
    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf);

        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        pdf = findViewById(R.id.pdf);

        button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            generatePdf();
        });
    }

    private void generatePdf() {
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        float height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        float width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

        int convertHeight = (int) height, convertWidth = (int) width;

        // создаем документ
        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
        // определяем размер страницы
        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo =
                new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(convertWidth, convertHeight, 1).create();
        // получаем страницу, на котором будем генерировать контент
        PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

        // получаем холст (Canvas) страницы
        Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);

        // получаем контент, который нужно добавить в PDF, и загружаем его в Bitmap
        Bitmap bitmap = loadBitmapFromView(pdf, pdf.getWidth(), pdf.getHeight());
        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, convertWidth, convertHeight, true);

        // рисуем содержимое и закрываем страницу
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
        document.finishPage(page);

        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/PDF");
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }

        // сохраняем записанный контент
        String targetPdf = dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/test.pdf";
        File filePath = new File(targetPdf);
        try {
            document.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PDf сохранён в " + filePath.getAbsolutePath(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Что-то пошло не так: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        // закрываем документ
        document.close();
    }

    public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v, int width, int height) {
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        v.draw(c);

        return b;
    }

}
```

Comment: вам надо использовать объект унаследованный от View у которого есть методы getWidth()/getHeight(), например TextView

Comment: В TextView я не смогу много других View поместить. Попробую другой объект использовать вместо TextView

Comment: Проверьте макет - у Вас просто не найден вью по `R.id.pdf`

Comment: Выложите разметку макета `activity_pdf`